# Plot range for line of fit using date on the x-axis in gnuplot

Tags: date, range, gnuplot

I am trying to plot the fit function (col 3 versus col 7) for my dataset given below

```
 28-08-1991 20-12-1992  24-04-1992  -263347200  -221875200  -242611200  0.060859 
 20-12-1992 02-09-1993  27-04-1993  -221875200  -199756800  -210816000  0.064681 
 10-09-1996 13-09-1997  13-03-1997  -104371200  -72576000   -88473600   0.095728 ......
```

I would like my script to plot the fit only for certain range of dates, say between 1995 to 2003. I am unable to get the range function right since the gnuplot handle the dates past the year 2000.

Please find my code below.

```
 set xdata time
 set timefmt "%d-%m-%Y"
 set xrange ["01-01-1991":"01-01-2015"]

 set yrange [0.0:0.4]
 offset = 24*60*60 
 f(x) = 1.e-7*m*(x-offset)+c 
 fit f(x) "file"  using 3:7  via m,c
 set fit logfile 'file.log' 
 plot '(x < "24-02-1993" ) ? f(x) : 1/0' title "Best fit" with lines ls 5
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable `x` in `plot` will contain the time in the form of seconds since 1/1/1970. So in order to compare it with a date, you need to convert that date to the same format with `strptime`.

If you additionally remove the `'` around the function to plot in your MWE, you get:

```
plot (x<strptime("%d-%m-%Y","24-02-1993"))?f(x):1/0 title "Best fit" with lines ls 5
```

Note that you've fitted `f(x)` over the whole dataset, not over dates before 24-02-1993, it's only the plot which is restricted to these dates.